# android studio issues, I can't open new activity with java

Tags: android-studio

when I open a new activity, the android studio allows me to write on Kotlin only, I want java, and I don't know the solution

Answer (score 1):

This will might be work for you.

**Clear Cache**

First go to Build -> Clean Project. (Clears your Build Folders)

Still not working the solution do below step :

File -> `Invalidate Caches / Restart`

**And still not working the remove your `.gradle` directory from the root of your project. It contains some Gradle cache files.**